# Mark Factory precedence GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

What does mark factory mean? Why and where do we use it?
Also, why do we enable mark factory precedence in WMS service using GeoServer?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: as the name suggests a `MarkFactory` is a factory for producing marks - you should probably never need to worry about them unless you are creating new and exciting marks that have never been seen before

Answer (score 1):

Mark Factory Precedence is a [new feature added in GeoServer 2.21.0](https://geoserver.org/announcements/2022/05/24/geoserver-2-21-0-released.html)

from the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/webadmin.html#mark-factory-precedence):

> Mark factories can be filtered and ordered during the rendering execution. This makes room to optimize the rendering phase by omitting unused mark factories and prioritizing the fastest ones.

So it is only necessary for you to set this if you are using a lot of marks that are generated by a factory and you want to move the one you are using to be first in the list of factories to be checked. Most users will never need to change this setting.